# problem on logic 0 at 4027 ic

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop

I have a circuit to generate simple sound with astable multivibrator and enable/disable it with j-k flip flop with reset pin, something like this pic:
[image]

i have a problem with logic 0, when it occurs the output is 10mv instead of 0, this 10mv send to my amp and occurred noisy voice.
how can i fix it?

Comment: It is totally unclear to me what you might be trying to achieve putting an analog signal into a digital chip like this. Maybe you have some link to a site that recommended this. I'm not even sure that you have applied a logic power supply to the chip.

Comment: Like Andy I think you question is unclear and therefore difficult to answer. If the 'sound signal' is coming from an astable (eg a 555) then all you need is a simple 2 input gate ( an AND) to control it. To prevent any DC getting through add a series capacitor (eg 100uF) between the gate output and the amp input. If the sound is an analogue signal you should use an analogue bilateral switch (such as a 4066).

Comment: @JImDearden thanks for ur suggestion. 100uf thats a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably caused by noise on the digital ground. One solution is to use a series diode as so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feOgkt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That will prevent noise on the digital ground relative to the amplifier ground of less than a couple hundred mV from being heard.

Comment: thank you, what is your idea about adding100uf capacitor before 1n4148 diode?

Comment: Okay, I see from reading the comments that your question about the 100uF cap was with regard to a series capacitor, not a cap to ground. I don't think that will help, but it won't hurt either. If you try to combine it with the diode suggestion above, it could hurt.